# Vulkan hpp How to properly handle deletion of unique handles in global scope?

Tags: c++, graphics, software-design, vulkan

I am trying to create a cache of shader modules in vulkan to avoid recompiling/recreating them after certain events (e.g swapchain recreation).

The data structure looks like this:

```
enum class ShaderStage
{
    VERTEX = 0,
    FRAGMENT
};
typedef std::map<ShaderStage, vk::UniqueShaderModule> ModuleData;
static std::map<std::string, ModuleData> data_cache;
```

Or in other words a map from a string identifier to the set of shader modules associated with a program, and then a map from each shader stage (fragment, vertex ...).

The issue with this is that the destructor of those global objects won't be call until we return from main, which messes up the correct order of object destruction for vulkan, leading to a segmentation fault.

This can be corrected by adding this function to my class:

```
static void CleanCache() { data_cache.clear(); }
```

If this function is called prior to main exiting, there will be no segmentation fault.

However this forces the potential user of my code to necessarily clear the cache manually before exiting main, something I would rather avoid.

I wanted to know if there is a technique I can use to implicitly destroy the objects before terminating the program.

Comment: Hard to answer without knowing more about what you're providing. If the user of your code owns the VkDevice and manages its lifetime directly, then I don't think there is -- whoever manages the VkDevice lifetime is also responsible for the lifetime of its child objects. But if you provide a wrapper or abstraction for the VkDevice, so that your code is invoked as part of VkDevice destruction, then that code could clear the cache -- and you probably also have a better place to store it than as a singleton global variable.

Comment: I am not providing the abstractions for the wrappers, `vk::Unique*` handles are provided by the vulkan.hpp header, a standar set of C++ bindings supported by the Lunar sdk. Those handles are in charge of appropriately freeing the resource upon destruction. They are RAIIS

Comment: @Makogan: "*Those handles are in charge of appropriately freeing the resource upon destruction.*" And the owner of those handles are in charge of destroying them when the resources they represent are no longer needed. So who is that?

Comment: "*I am trying to create a cache of shader modules in vulkan to avoid recompiling/recreating them after certain events (e.g swapchain recreation).*" Why would swapchain building have anything to do with the creation of shaders and pipelines?

Comment: @NicolBolas If the window changes the swapchain needs to be recreated, according to the vulkan tutorial. Which in turn forces a recreation of all objects depending on on the swapchain, accoridng to the tutorial:

https://vulkan-tutorial.com/Drawing_a_triangle/Swap_chain_recreation

Comment: @NicolBolas "Who is that", they are static variables of a class, it would be the class they belong to. Who currently handles that responsibility by providing a CleanCache method, as described in the question.

Comment: @Makogan: But someone has to be responsible for calling that method, and calling it at the right time. Whoever that is is the code that owns those resources. C++ is not Java or Python or whatever; someone has to have responsibility for cleaning up resources.

Comment: Very few things should depend on the swapchain though. You need new VkImages and VkImageViews, and therefore new VkFramebuffer objects (unless you use the brand new VK_KHR_imageless_framebuffer extension) and VkCommandBuffers. But usually you're re-creating command buffers anyway. You'd need to update descriptor sets that refer to the old VkImageViews, if any (typically there aren't). But your VkRenderPass and VkPipeline objects shouldn't depend on the swapchain.